# Azure CDN doesn't respect Blob's CORS

Tags: azure, cors, blob, cdn

I have an Azure Blob with the CORS configured and functional (my website is able to access the resources via XMLHttpRequest).

But when I access the resources through the Azure CDN, I have the "**XMLHttpRequest cannot load X. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'X' is therefore not allowed access.**" error.

I have read that CDN should take the Blob CORS into account, but it's obviously not the case here.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I still have this problem :(

Answer (score -1):

It's enabled but you still have to set it up. 
You will need to have the CDN serve the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:mydomain.com
```

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx) provides a bit of explanation to configure the service.

Comment: The article is about CORS on storage service, it's already my case (my blob is set-up and is working without the CDN)